# Notation help for matrices - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I am first told that there is a matrix $A.$

What does this then mean when
$$\left[A \mid\, \vec{0}\right]$$ is the augmented matrix of a linear system?

What does it mean for $A$ to have $\mid\; \vec 0$ next to it?

Answer (score 2):

$[A\ |\ \vec 0]$ simply means that a column of zeros is added to the matrix $A$. For example, if
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&2&3\\2&1&0\\-1&2&-3},
$$
then
$$
[A\ \ |\ \ \vec 0]  = \pmatrix{1&2&3&0\\2&1&0&0\\-1&2&-3&0}.
$$
Often, this matrix is written with a vertical line. That is, we might write
$$
[A \ \ | \ \ \vec 0] = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&2&3&0\\2&1&0&0\\-1&2&-3&0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Mathematically, it makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I finally understand what | 0⃗ ]  means.

However, could you kindly clarify about why it makes no difference mathematically.
Thank you

Comment: @KingRand16 It's difficult to clarify why something doesn't make a difference. If you have a context where you believe that it should make a difference, I could explain why you get the same result either way

Comment: @KingRand16 That said: if you're solving linear systems, then you're probably only applying row operations to these matrices. Note that whether or not the line is written to indicate the division, the change to each entry as a result of the row operation will be exactly the same.